# meaning of the "meant by"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I often see questions started with "what is meant by...". What is "meant by"?

Any trying to Google it returns nothing helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like [General Reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mean_1) to me - *"What is meant by X?"* = *"What does X mean?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It can also be used as a reprimand. 'What is meant by your boorish behaviour?'

Comment: The biggest irony of this question is that _what is the meaning of_ is quite similar to _what is meant by_.  The two phrases are nearly interchangeable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is meant by `X`?*

is the passive form of

> *What does `X` mean?*

The idiomatic construction *is meant by* allows one to ask a question about meaning,
without having  to leave the verb *mean* till the end of the question. If you want to know about the meaning  of something, it makes sense to turn on the meaning detector and **then** say what the word is, instead of saying the word before you get to asking about its meaning.

Other question constructions like

- *What is the meaning of `X`?*

are common, for the same reason.

*Mean*, btw, is an irregular weak verb; i.e,
its past tense form and past participle form are identical
like weak verbs;
however, they're irregular in that they don't use the -ED suffix, but rather -T;
**and** they change pronunciation.

- *mean, meant, meant* is the list of principal parts of the verb, but
  /**mi:n, mɛnt, mɛnt**/ is their pronunciation.

Comment: Same thing happens with *lean, leant*, although not without increasing competition with *lean, leaned*.  The only other example like that I could find was *ween* (**not** *wean*, but the one from the OE weak verb *wénan*), whose past & pa.pple. *w(h)ent(e)* forms disappeared even before the verb itself did.  You can find *ween* in the 19th century, but only as an intentional archaism.  I’m thinking that colliding with *lend, lent* and *wend, went* hasn’t helped the other two.

Comment: I don't know what motivations were for making this question as off-topic, but this answer pretty clear for my. Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know either; sometimes people don't recognize what the question is, without context.

Answer (score 2):

It means: what is the likely *intent* of the use a phrase.

This can be its direct communicative intent, or else the intention regarding tone, style, structure, and so on. It assumes that the use is a deliberate act, and seeks the reasoning behind that act.

Of course, this is strongly determined by context which is why supplying sufficient context to such questions is vital.

It has a range of meanings, of course, determined by context, but they principally ask for an interpretation of something in the fields of *semantics* or *pragmatics* in determining such *denotation* or *connotations* of a phrase.